# Error trying to configure esx_addonaccount

Tags: lua

I am trying to make a fivem server and have been able to configure esx_addonaccount once before, but now that I have needed to restart my project it is not seeming to work. My database is considered fine, and I am running a completely vanilla install minus the esx framework plugins and esx_addonaccount, which is the problem. This occurs when I load into the server anytime.

```
Error running system event handling function for resource esx_addonaccount: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:41: Failed to execute thread: @esx_addonaccount/server/main.lua:87: attempt to index a nil value (local 'xPlayer')
stack traceback:
        @esx_addonaccount/server/main.lua:87: in upvalue 'handler'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:219: in function <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:218>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:41: in field 'CreateThreadNow'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:218: in function <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:182>
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

> @esx_addonaccount/server/main.lua:87: attempt to index a nil value (local 'xPlayer')

Above is a line from your error. It basically says that in resource `esx_addonaccount`, in folder `./server/`, in file `main.lua`, in line `87` you are trying to access `xPlayer` variable, but in this specific case it equals `nil`. This means that either you have not initialized ESX correctly or somehow `xPlayer` is not existing - eg. player with given ID doesn't exist.

The best bet would be to check the whole 'path' of this variable - where is it created, initialized and populated with data.

ESX resources should work out of the box, so if it doesn't, then try to follow the installation instructions in their README files or on github and see if you did everything to correctly install them on your server.